# May an instance be committed if an exception occurs in the post_save handler?

Tags: python, django, django-signals

I have a `post_save` handler that inserts additional records into the database referring to the instance that was just created or updated. However, an error (perhaps a constraint violation) may occur when inserting the additional records.

If an exception occurs in the `post_save` handler, is it still possible that the initial instance will be committed?

The answer might depend on these sub-questions:

- Does Django's auto-commit mode commit before or after the `post_save` signal?
- Does Django attempt to use nested transactions to rollback the instance being saved if an error occurs in `post_save`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the docs, if you are using `autocommit` changes to the initial instance will be committed on `.save()` before any `post_save` signal handler. An exception in `post_save` will not rollback the changes to the initial instance.

You can confirm this by looking at the source to `save_base` in `django/db/models/base.py`. The autocommit would occur [on line 555](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/db/models/base.py#L555) (in 1.4.2), but the `post_save` signal isn't sent [until line 564](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.4.2/django/db/models/base.py#L564). You can also see that Django does not attempt to use any nested transactions in `.save()`.

If you are using `django.middleware.transaction.TransactionMiddleware` and have not overridden its behavior with an `autocommit` decorator, an exception during `post_save` would rollback the entire transaction, including the changes to the initial instance.